# Why doesn't this drop down menu from a Webdesigndev article work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on dropdown menu's. Nothing fancy, just a simple combination of HTML, CSS and jQuery. I've found a good example but when trying to implement it in my own website I somehow can't get it to work.

Therefore a dumbed it down to a little dummy that basically COPIED what was said in the article that was helping me out with the menu's, and somehow it still does not work, and I can't figure out why.

Could someone explain to me what I did wrong in the dummy, so I can use that as an example whilst trying to fix the intended menu?

[Article with the dropdown code](http://www.webdesigndev.com/web-development/create-the-fanciest-dropdown-menu-you-ever-saw#basicmenu/) (go the the part that says basic code, fancy is still too far from my grasp)

The HTML dummy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" title="nzoom" type="text/css" href="opmaak_home.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
</body>
```

The .css dummy:

```
/* tabs
*************************/

ul.tabs
{
display: table;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
}

ul.tabs li
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
display: table-cell;
float: left;
position: relative;
}

ul.tabs a
{
position: relative;
display: block;
}

/* dropdowns
*************************/

ul.dropdown
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
top: 100%;
width: 250px;
display: none;
left: 0;
}

ul.dropdown ul.dropdown
{
top: 0;
left: 95%;
}

ul.dropdown li
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: none;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
display: block;
}

ul.dropdown li a
{
display: block;
}
```

The jQuery dummy:

```
$(function () {

    $('.dropdown').each(function () {
        $(this).parent().eq(0).hover(function () {
            $('.dropdown:eq(0)', this).show();
        }, function () {
            $('.dropdown:eq(0)', this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Will you explain what doesn't work, exactly? What do you expect to happen, what is happening now, and what errors do you see on the debugging console?

Comment: put the javascript:`<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>` in the head

Comment: Works exactly the same in the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NZM97/ - as it does in the example. You need to actually include the jQuery library.

Comment: Are you actually including the jQuery library anywhere in your file?

Comment: Are you loading jquery? It isn't in your code

Comment: Yet another question where the Too Localized close option could be useful...

Comment: @JoeFrambach I'm a little lost without it haha..

Comment: Eh I guess the off topic > no research option is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included the jquery library.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: It should be noted that this should be included in the document _before_ the Javascript that attempts to use it.

Comment: and now i feel ever so stupid...
However thanks to everyone for the swift and helpfull responses.